# Can I control the Office message bar programatically (Protected View Window)

Tags: ms-word, vsto, ms-office, office-interop, office-2010

In Office, a yellow or red message bar is sometimes shown below the ribbon.  It is usually red for security related messages, and yellow for information messages.

The screenshot below shows *MS Access* displaying a typical message bar.

[image: Screenshot of yellow message bar in MS Access]

I would like to create a small *Word* add-on that programatically uses this UI feature.  Is that possible?  I've searched the [MSDN information on customizing Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620922.aspx) but can't find any reference on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer to my own question so far is to style a [custom task pane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa942864.aspx) to look like the yellow panel, and to use [`DockPositionRestrict`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpane.dockpositionrestrict.aspx) to prevent it from being moved.  Not marking this as the answer just yet in case anyone knows of something better.

Comment: Save yourself the pain, this isn't possible because there's a minimum height for custom panes when docked vertically.

Comment: Consider using a modeless UserForm, message box or mouse-over pop-up text. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/pop-up-text-in-microsoft-word/f070b772-7d8e-4a29-8943-bca01967cb76?tm=1609428405945

Answer (score 1):

I think, in Office's terms, the message bar is actually called `Protected View Window`. There is an API for it, [ProtectedViewWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.protectedviewwindow.aspx), both available for Word & Excel interop.

Take a look at its [properties and methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.protectedviewwindow_members.aspx), it'd be helpful to you.

For example, use `ProtectedViewWindow.Caption` to add your custom messages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've now looked into it, but it's evidently [a new security feature](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2010/09/13/object-model-considerations-for-protected-view-in-word-2010.aspx).  I'm trying improve integration between our existing document management system and *Word*.